# Full HTML body content is not showing

Tags: 7

I am using Druapal 7 and wyswing editor. i used full HTML. Now my body content is not showing .Can anybody tell me the reason.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the whole body content does no show up on saving the node?

Comment: You mean the content of the field? Or "content" area of your template? And is it not visible but present in HTML, or not rendered to HTML at all?

Comment: Please elaborate little bit...

Comment: yeah whole body content is not showing

Comment: Are you wishing to use the CK Editor for this...??

Comment: yes, i am using it . but content is not displaying now

Comment: What will be displayed when you switch to plain text mode or filter mode?

Comment: it will show my content